# How do I split Turbosquid Obj/FBX collection into separate 3D Models?

Tags: modeling

I'm working on landscape design app (iOS) and want to use pre-existing 3D Models from turbosquid. They come in collections bundled as .obj or .fbx files. [Example](https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/xfrogplants-hdplants-1-3d-1724758)

What's the best way to break down these collections into individual self-contained objects (with their texture files/light/camera etc) that I can directly use in my scene with Scenekit/ARKit?

Comment: Hi :). You can separate the geometry using *Mesh > Separate > by loose parts* (in Edit mode). Or by selection, to only separate a part.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this on one of the collections I had and the result was it broke it down into ~8300 geometries. Not something I was expecting.

Comment: Hi :). Well, you can of course separate them manually. Select a face, then Ctrl+L to select the linked geometry. And Mesh -> Separate > Selection

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me as expected and solved my problem.